# At some position character cannot see the whole mesh in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, transparent, mesh, visible

I want to show a transparent building in our project. I did that by setting the material of the mesh to be "transparent/diffuse". However, there exists some visibility problem of the mesh of the building. At some position, I can only see two or three sides of the cuboid(the transparent block, i.e the building). If I adjust my character position, I can see the whole cuboid. I googled the similar question online, someone mentioned about the frustum view of the camera. It seems like character has to be inside the frustum view of the camera, then user can see the whole mesh of the cuboid.

Can anyone give me some suggestions? I feel like it might be something about the way of how I build my mesh for the building, but at some position, I can see the whole cuboid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've solved this problem. It is just about the way how you construct the mesh.Basically, for the cuboid, I reconstructed the mesh in this way:

```
triangles[0]=topleft;
triangles[1]=topright;
triangles[2]=bottomright;
triangles[3]=bottomright;
triangles[4]=bottomleft;
triangles[5]=topleft;
```

Note: This is just front side, the other sides should be constructed in a same way.
Besides, in order to show the mesh when user enters the block, you have to construct the inside area of the block in previous way.